# Using pointer Notation to print an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, printing

I would like to point out some random integers using the regular print function, then print again the same integers using pointer notation. When I use pointer notation I run into some trouble. If anyone could send some tips it'd be much appreciated. If i comment out a specific line of code, the program will compile completely, but not with the outputs I'd like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>     //srand(), rand()

using namespace std;

void printArray(int[], int);
//void printToday(int , );

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   const int SZ = 100;
   int myArray[SZ] ={0};
   srand(time(0));
   int myArrayTotal = 0;
   int *thelight;
   thelight = myArray;

   for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++)
   {
      myArray[i]= i+rand()%1000 ;
   }

   cout << "Array Notation:\n\n";
   printArray(myArray, SZ);
   system("pause");
   system("cls");

   cout << "Pointer Notation: \n\n";
   int k = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
      {
         cout<< *(thelight + k)<< "\t";
         ++k; //if I comment out this line the second part of the program will run, but it isn' the values I want.
      }   cout<< endl;
   }
}

void printArray(int ArrayName[], int ArraySize)
{
   int k = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < 10 ; ++j)
      {
         cout << ArrayName[k] << "\t";
         ++k;
      }cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: try cout<< *(thelight + k * sizeof(int))<< "\t";

Comment: You are accessing the array out of bounds when you are filling it up with random numbers. The conditional in the `if` statement needs to be `i < 100`, not `i <= 200`. Better still, use `i < SZ`.

Comment: I see, TY @RSahu, it wasn't in the pointer notation, but the initialization of the Array. Thank you!!

Comment: @Nandu, that would be a mistake. `(thelight + k)` is sufficient to move the pointer by the right offset.